# CSS3 not being displayed with Internet Explorer 10

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just started learning HTML5, CSS3 & Javascript along with bootstrap for responsive websites. i have come across a strange problem. The below index.html page displays correctly in firefox and chrome but no styles apply when viewing in IE10. Could someone please take a look at this code to tell me what am I missing here? I would like this to appear with styles in IE10 as well.
Note: I did some investigation and found out that if the style tag is inside the html along with the styles, it appears fine in IE but when I reference the style sheet from outside, no styles apply.
Also I have some jquery and bootstrap files inside my main folder.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Module 3 Assignment</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  </head>
<body>
   <header>
   <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">

      <!-- here goes logo
      <a href="index.html" class="pull-left">
      </a> -->

      <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a href="index.html"><h1>Website Name</h1>
      </a>
      </div>

      <!-- collapsible button for menu  -->
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          </div>

           <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
           <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#" class="visible-xs">Genius</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="visible-xs">Smart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="visible-xs">Average</a></li>
          </ul><!-- #nav-list -->
        </div><!-- .collapse .navbar-collapse --> 
  </div>
</nav>

  </header>

  <h1><p class="text-center">Types Of Individuals</h1> 
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  <div id="box1" class="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-xs-12"> 
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 
  Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. 
  Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. 
  Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, 
  venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. 
   </p>  
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <!-- jQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css that is inside the css folder in the project folder.

```
h1 p{
   padding-top:40px;
   padding-bottom:30px;
  }

#header-nav{
  background-color:gray;
  border-radius:0;
  border: 0; 
}


 .navbar-brand h1 { /* Restaurant name */
  font-family: 'Oxygen', serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #222;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: .75;
  padding-left:5px;

}

.navbar-brand{
   padding-top:20px;


}

#nav-list a:hover{
  background: #E7E7E7;

  }

  #nav-list a{

    color:black;
    font-size:1.0em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#7FFFD4;

  }

.navbar-brand a:hover, .navbar-brand a:focus{
    text-decoration:none;
}


  .row {
  width: 100%;

   }

    .navbar-header button.navbar-toggle, .navbar-header .icon-bar {
      border:2px solid black;

      }


  #box1 {
    border:3px solid black; 
    width:90%;
    height:1000px;
    background-color:gray;
    color:white;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
  }

  #box1 p{

    font-family:'Oxygen', serif;
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5%;

  }

  /********** Large devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {


  }

  /********** Medium devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {


  }

  /********** Small devices only **********/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {



  }     

  /********** Extra small devices only **********/
@media (max-width: 767px) {




}

/********** Super extra small devices Only :-) (e.g., iPhone 4) **********/
@media (max-width: 479px) {


}
```

Comment: If no styles are present, you css is not loading ... check and make sure that the css is being loaded.

Comment: Can you open the console and show us what error messages you're seeing?

Comment: Not an answer to you problem, but two small things to think about. You can save requests by adding all Google Fonts in one link as: '<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700|Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>'  Also, don't duplicate jQuery since it can cause problems. Remove the one in the header since you have it in the end of the document.

Comment: The error log says"The server understands the request but is refusing to fulfill it" and it's pointing to these links.<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> and also <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: These links are in the header for bootstrap purposes

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#search=css3 CSS3 only has 75% overall support in ie11, 21% in ie8, so i'm afraid you're just outta luck..

Comment: Is there any way to make it appear at least decent for older IE browsers?New to html & css.